# write apache httpd access log entries to oracle database

Tags: apache2

is there a way to send apache access log entries to oracle database at runtime...analyzing those entries from database instead of parsing access.log file is far better...i found some modules for logging this to myssql database but has somebody done that for oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would etl my logs into oracle from the existing logs on the filesystem perodically.  If the database has issues, it affects your webserver, not to mention that write times to the database will typically be slower (making a socket connection, updating indexes during the insert, etc).